# When is the riemann integral of a finite-variation process square-integrable?

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes

Let us say $X_t$ is a continuous finite-variation process and $f(t, x)$ a $C^{1, 1}$ function. We define
$$
Y_t = \int^t_0 f(s, X_s)\, \mathrm ds
$$
Are there any general results pertaining to conditions one must have on $f(t, x)$ and/or $X_t$ in order to have
$$
\mathbb E [Y_t^2]<\infty \qquad \forall t \in [0, T]
$$
for $T<\infty$?

Comment: $$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t f(s,X_s)^2 \, ds \right)<\infty$$ is a sufficient condition.